# Apple rejected the app because of beta in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

Apple rejected the build with the below message 
"To resolve this issue, please remove all references to "demo," "trial," "beta," or "test" in your app description, app icon, screenshots, previews, release notes, and binary. If you would like to conduct a beta trial for your app, you may wish to review the TestFlight Beta Testing Guide."

I have not enabled any beta build, just the Testflight is enabled for internal testers no external testers and beta build.

This is the screenshot dialogue shared by Apple: [image]

I am not sure how to remove this beta dialogue as I have not enabled that and this is coming auto from Apple in-app purchase dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is sometimes rejecting without a valid reason. Just try to resolve it by replying to the rejection and mention that this message is because of the beta program.

Answer (score -1):

Disable all demo or Testing or Beta mode.App build will be look like a live app then add it for approval.And also remove text which is coming anywhere in app, which is related to the Beta/testing/demo.

Comment: Everything is disabled, can you please specifically answer which modes you are talking.

Comment: remove all text related to testing mode